# 2000 Fleetwood Southwind - Where do I refill the leveling jacks with hydraulic fluid?

Tags: troubleshooting

Pretty much all in the subject...the level jack lights stay on even when fully retracted, which I think is a sign of low fluid levels. I've got the hydraulic fluid, but I can't figure out where in the $(*&%$ to refill it.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reservoir should be underneath the chassis - follow a hydraulic line from one of the levelers back to its source.

Fill plug should near the top.

Comment: I determined today that, at least on my model (2000), it is located behind the right front wheel. You will need to crawl entirely under the vehicle and then sit on your knees in a small well underneath the vehicle. I think I just remembered why I had kids...

Answer (score 2):

I found my hydraulic reservoir for 2000 southwind fleetwood behind passenger tire (behind mudflap). It's tight and crammy and I had to sit straight up with little to no space to work with. Absolutely one of the worst things I would like to avoid doing again but let's face it...It's inevitable lol.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Great information! I'm sure someone will be able to use this going forward.